# IE7 maddeningly displaying columns under a div instead of over it

Tags: css, internet-explorer, z-index

If you view this page in IE7: http://65.60.10.2/~marionin/ , why are the light purple headers ("Spotlights", "Serendipity Projects", "Marion Institute Blog") hiding underneath the dark purple band?

I have firebugged till my fingers hurt, but I can't figure it out. The column divs are written after the block div, so they should display on top.
 Mucking about with the z-index doesn't help, even when setting the positions of the block and the columns to relative.

[Of course, as would be expected, everything looks fine in Firefox, Safari, Opera, and Chrome.]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#block-block-11 {
    position: static;
}
```

...quick fix to a larger issue eloquently detailed by CalebD.

Comment: Holy moly, I love me a one-line fix!  Thanks!

Comment: FYI it actually sidesteps the issue broached by CalebD because it removes that block from z-index consideration.  You might want to consider fixing the larger issue at some point.  Glad I could help though.

Answer (score 1):

IE has terrible z-index bugs that are often impossible to grok. I was able to make it behave in IE 7 after some fiddling with the IE developer toolbar.

I noticed that for some reason many elements had z-index defined on them yet these weren't appearing in the HTML. Do you have a script running that is setting any z-indexes? I noticed that they were in reverse order, meaning that the high level elements had higher z-indexes than the lower level elements. This is one way to create numerous bugs in IE. The deeper the HTML appears in the hierarchy, the higher its z-index should be.

I started by removing the z-index on the relevant containers, from body down to the two `<div>`s in `#main-content`. I set `position: relative` on `#main-content` but left `z-index` undefined. I set `position: relative` on the two `<div>`s in `#main-content` and set the `z-index` to 100 and 200 respectively.

Within `#content`, the first `<div>`, I added `z-index: 110` and the second `<div>` (the row of blocks with small pictures) I added `z-index: 120`.

That seemed to get IE 7 to behave correctly.

If there is anything else that has a `z-index` defined that I didn't mention, try removing it and starting from the ground up. The less elements there are with `z-index` defined, the less opportunity there is for IE to behave badly.

Comment: Thanks for the rundown!   Yeah, at this point a bunch of those z-indexes are leftovers from trying to fix this (and other) display issues.  It's like digging myself into a freakin' hole!

Comment: Ohhhh, I think that many of those z-indexes have to do with the little rotating js slideshow thingie.  And my take on it is that "static" basically says "scrap all that and behave like normal from now on".  Sweet.